# A (blank)'s worth

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

How does one say "a (noun)'s worth of (noun)"? For instance: "I have a month's worth of work that I must finish in only one week!".

This question was asked on Facebook, and I wanted to capture some of the answers here.

Answer (score 4):

The best answer in my opinion involves the use of ***da*** - but with the warning that sometimes expression like this are not clear.

- *Monaton da laboro mi devas plenumi en unu sola semajno.*

Some other suggestions involved rewording the sentence.

- *Laboron, kiom mi normale faras en unu monato, mi devos fari en nur unu semajno!*

If *monato da* doesn't seem clear, you can be more specific.

- *Monata kvanto da laboro*
- *Taga kvanto da manĝaĵo*

While disucssing "two minutes worth of charge"

- *La baterio de mia poŝtelefono elĉerpiĝos post du minutoj*
- *Mia poŝtelefono havas duminutan kvanton de baterio/ŝargo*
- *Restas nur du minutoj en mia baterio*
- La ŝargo de mia telefono daŭros nur du minutojn".

Original post
https://www.facebook.com/groups/duolingo.esperanto.learners/permalink/699877620174258/

Comment: I believe you're mistaken about that. My suggestion would be to post your own answer saying this. Be sure to include references and examples that you've found of people using the word in this way.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of Tomas, I think that one can also use word 'amplekso' instead of 'kvanto':

*Monatan amplekson de la laboro mi devas plenumi dum nur unu semajno*

The fraze *amplekso de la laboro* doesn't used often: three occurrences en the Tekstaro and one in translation of [Faust](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vqUT0GoWJAIC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=amplekso+de+la+laboro&source=bl&ots=8BCovpCN3X&sig=axVgKa3n3468wcV25hS5pC8Kg4s&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPmPauz_LQAhXLESwKHU4XDu4Q6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=amplekso%20de%20la%20laboro&f=false).